# Absolute positioning inside relative positioning

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a little problem with my short code. [Here](http://www.pugganagga.com/) you will find my website.
It's only a image with a button on it. My problem is, that now the button moves around when I want to scale the browser window. Therefore the button would be anyplace else on different browsers, computers, mobile phones,...

This is my code:

```
<center>

<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
  <img src="/images/home2.png" style="position: relative; bottom: 0; left: 0;"/>
    <div style="position: absolute; right: 300; bottom: 250;">
      <a href="http://www.pugganagga.com/"><img src=" /images/button.gif " onmouseover="this.src='  /images/button2.gif '" onmouseout="this.src='  /images/button.gif '"  /></a>
    </div>
</div>

</center>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0; margin: 0 auto; width:892px">
  <img src="/images/home2.png" style="position: relative; bottom: 0; left: 0;">
  <div style="position: absolute; right: -145px; bottom: 250;">
    <a href="http://www.pugganagga.com/"><img src="  /images/button.gif " onmouseover="this.src='  /images/button2.gif '" onmouseout="this.src='  /images/button.gif '"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, your `div` is full-width of browser window, the `position: absolute` applies to the full-width of your `div` and not to the width of your image. Furthermore you should export your styles to an extern `.css` file, inline `.css` is not the best technique.

here is what you should change

```
<div style="position: relative;background: url(/images/home2.png);width: 800px;height: 800px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; right: 30px; bottom: 125px;">
    <a href="http://www.pugganagga.com/"><img src="  /images/button.gif " onmouseover="this.src='  /images/button2.gif '" onmouseout="this.src='  /images/button.gif '">
    </a>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

here is a better way to achieve what you want with CSS

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="button">
    <a href="http://www.pugganagga.com/"><img src="  /images/button.gif " onmouseover="this.src='  /images/button2.gif '" onmouseout="this.src='  /images/button.gif '">
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
   position: relative;
   background: url(/images/home2.png);
   width: 800px;
   height: 800px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
.button{
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 125px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be one of the options. This will fix the image in a constant place. Try this out.

```
<div style="position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0;">   

<img src="/images/home2.png" style="position: fixed; left: 453; top: 449;"/>
<div style="position: absolute; right: 300; bottom: 250;">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Well lot of problems with this code :)**

First, you don't need to set `left: 0`, or `top: 0` on element that have `position:relative;`. When you use coordinates on relative positionning, it means : go on XXpx of the top of its current place. **So when you put 0, you mean : stay at your current place**.

Then, I cleaned up your code :

```
<body background="http://www.pugganagga.com/images/giftly.png" text="#990000" link="#0000CC" vlink="#000066" alink="#000000">     
<div style="width: 800px; margin: 10px auto; position: relative; ">
  <img src="/images/home2.png" >
    <div style="position: absolute; right: 50px; bottom: 250px;">
      <a href="http://www.pugganagga.com/"><img src="  /images/button.gif " onmouseover="this.src='  /images/button2.gif '" onmouseout="this.src='  /images/button.gif '"></a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

*I removed obsolete `center` tag, remove useless `position: relative' and used units for coordinates (200px instead of 200, as in CSS, it means nothing).*